# How to get an array from number positions of other array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `A = [1,3]` - which stores positions of correct answers from another array `B = ["answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]`.
I need to get an array **C** which will be consist from the correct answers, something like this `["answer1","answer3"]`.

Example: If array **A** consist from 1 element (for example `A = [2]`), then array **C** should look like `C = ["answer2"]`.

I can solve this problem with `indexOf()`, when I have an array **A** consisting from 1 element. But when there are 2 or more elements I'm getting stuck

Comment: An alternative solution to @Ilia Komarov's perfect one can be: `for (var i in A) C += B[A[i]-1]` Just to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do something like:

```js
let A = [1,3];
let B = ["answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"];
let C = A.map(i => B[i-1]);
```